# Column of 0's created in call to r table() function, but there are no 0's in the columns used for the call

Tags: r, dataframe, chi-squared, r-table

I am slightly new to R, and I am running into a problem. I have a data set that I am working on, and trying to preform a chi squared test on two of columns. However whenever I call the table function in R to make a crosstab to use in the chi squared test it adds a row and column of 0's even though there are no zeros in either of the columns. This is causing my chi squared test to produce a pvalue of nan and I cannot figure out where this extra column and row of zeros is coming from.

```
copy = ecomm_df[!(is.na(ecomm_df$profile) | is.na(ecomm_df$purchasedBefore)),]

tab = table(copy$profile,copy$purchasedBefore)

chi_test = chisq.test(tab)

chi_test$expected

copy
```

below is the example of when I call table on the two dataframe columns

[output of the table call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG8m5.png)

where might these extra row and column becoming from?

Comment: Are these two variables factors? What levels do they have?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.